Net month calendar SetSelectionRange for datas across multiple months
I would like to know if it is possible to select days in a month calendar using the SetSelectionRange method or the SelectionStart and SelectionEnd, with dates across several months. I'm coding in VB.NET
For exemple:
Me.Calendario_Mes.SetSelectionRange(New DateTime(2018, 4, 24), New DateTime(2018, 4, 30))
Me.Calendario_Mes.SetSelectionRange(New DateTime(2018, 5, 1), New DateTime(2018, 5, 31))
Me.Calendario_Mes.SetSelectionRange(New DateTime(2018, 6, 1), New DateTime(2018, 6, 16))
or
Me.Calendario_Mes.SelectionStart = Me.UltraGridResultado.ActiveRow.Cells("DATA_INICIO").Value // 2018-04-24
Me.Calendario_Mes.SelectionEnd = Me.UltraGridResultado.ActiveRow.Cells("DATA_FIM").Value // 2018-06-16
What I pretend it is to navigate between months and view the selected dates highlighted.
Regards
